# How to use transaction in loopback4

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I am using Loopback4 with Postgresql, and I try to use transaction in the code, but I can not find any documents that mention **Loopback4** transaction.

All I found it previous documents on loopback3.x (I try to install it, it can not be installed right now) or loopback2 in javascript.

I use **lb4** command to create all models, repositories, controllers.

Then, how do I apply transactions on these models or repositories?

Anyone could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transaction support in Loopback4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604916/transaction-support-in-loopback4)

Answer (score 0):

Loopback 4 does not support transactions out of the box. See [Transaction support in Loopback4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604916/transaction-support-in-loopback4)
. An issue has been opened on github here and a pull request was made.  See:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1599

Comment: This is no longer true: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604916/transaction-support-in-loopback4/1632256#61632256